# Solving a system of set equations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A, B, C be arbitrary sets. Solve this system of equations, and find necessary and sufficient conditions for existence and uniqueness of the solution:

$A \cup X = B\cap X$

$A \cap X = C \cup X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any sets $U,V$, we have $U\cap V\subseteq U \subseteq U\cup V$.

So, from the first one:
$$B\cap X\subseteq X\subseteq A\cup X = B\cap X $$
so all these must be $=$, and from the second one:
$$A\cap X\subseteq X\subseteq C\cup X = A\cap X$$
... can you continue?

Comment: Well, from these we have $X \subseteq A \subseteq X$, and that gives us $X = A$.
Putting $X = A$ in previous equations, we have $A = B \cap A = C \cup A$, so $C \subseteq A \subseteq B$.
Is this OK?
I still don't really get that part about ''necessary and sufficient conditions'', but I'll try to wrap my head around that.